# ssh key not working on mac machines

Tags: macos, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I already have the `id_rsa` keys inside my `.ssh` file (with passphrase)

Now, I would like to add new key so that I could connect to the server with ssh without password.

I do it like:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
>> /Users/markoz/.ssh/id_rsa_new
>> Passphrase:
```

now I have both keys inside `.ssh` folder

```
.ssh $ ls
id_rsa    id_rsa.pub    id_rsa_new    id_rsa_new.pub    known_hosts
```

Now if I copy the `id_rsa_new.pub` key into server `authorized_keys`, it doesn't work (it ask me for password)

But if I copy key of the `id_rsa.pub` key into server `authorized_keys` it works (ask for passphrase)

Did I miss something? Is there a rule that only one kew can be used?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default ssh takes `~/.ssh/id_rsa` key. You should specify it explicitly if different - use `$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa_new host`, for example.

Comment: can I specify witch key to use for witch host? (not every time)

Comment: For that you need to create `~/.ssh/config` file (`IdentityFile` option defines the private key to use). See https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config/ for reference.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get you